# Dojo addOnUnload function : How to include confirmation

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have some dojo code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      dojo.require("dojo.io.script");       

      var unload = function refreshParent(){
         confirmExit();
       }        

     dojo.addOnUnload(window, "unload");                
</script> 

function confirmExit()
{
  var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to close the window without saving it?");

  if (r==true)
  {
    window.returnValue=true;
    window.close();
  }
 else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The scenario is: On clicking on close for a window, the dojo unload gets called which closes the window.

However, I want a dialog box which asks for confirmation about the closing and if the user hits `Cancel`, the closing of the window should be disposed off.

However, currently, no matter what I do, the window is getting closed.

What could be the solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the confirmExit value

```
  var unload = function refreshParent(e){
     return confirmExit();
   }
```